# ActiveRecord order not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my controller, after reprioritizing a "child", this lists the children in their new order: `@child.parent.children.sort_by{|g| g.priority }`

This, surprisingly, doesn't work: `@child.parent.children.order(priority: :asc)`

Why doesn't `.order` work? Instead of sorting correctly, it's sorting by the PREVIOUS order before this operation was run, so I assume it's using cached results (the query is run before in the operation). How does one bust that cache, if that is indeed the problem? I've tried `@child.reload` after the reprioritizing to no avail.

Answer (score 11):

if you have some ordering on your `children` association you might try to use `reorder` to apply new ordering:

```
@child.parent.children.reorder(priority: :asc)
```